# Storing parameters for rules

Tags: drools, redhat-bpm

I am using RdeHat Decision Maker 7.1 (Drools) to create a rule for assigning a case to a department. The rule itself is quite simple, however it requires quite a lot of parameters (~12) like the agent type, working area, case type, customer seniority and more. The result "action" is the department to which the case is assigned.

I tried to place the parameters in a decision table , but the table quickly bloated to over 15,000 rows and will probably get even larger then that. I did, however, notices that in many cases the different between two rows is 1 or two parameters (e.g. same row with the only different is agent type "Local" vs. "Regional") resulting in different assignment.

I am thinking of replacing the table with something else, like a tree structure, so I can group similar rows under the same node and then navigate over the tree to make the decision. To do this I plan to prioritize the parameters and give parameters with higher priority a higher place in the tree.

Does anyone has experience with such a problem ? I looked at decision trees but they focus more on ML and probabilities, so I'm not sure this is what I need.

Is there any other method to deal with bloated tables that become unmanageable ? I cannot go to our customer and ask them to maintain a 15,000 rows excel. They'll shoot me there and then.

Thanks
Alon.

Comment: Are you really wanting to use decision tables, or are you willing to use DRL? This is pretty simple use case for DRL since you can just extend other rules.

Comment: I have no problem with DRL or Java.  The question in how to store the parameters (in a table ? a tree ?)